# Filter objects in list in a parent list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of one type (A) that contains various properties in addition to another list of type (B). I would like to filter out the objects in the child list (of type B) that don't have a particular property value.

For example, I have a list of Stores. Inside this list of stores I have another list of Brands (which contains objects with various properties). I want to filter out all of the items in the Brands list that don't have the 'Variety' property equal to 5., and then return the Stores list with the filtered out items in the Brands list.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
        foreach (var store in stores)
        {
            var brands = store.Brands.Where(x => x.Detail.Variety == 5).ToList();
        }
```

but I don't know how to replace this new set of brands with the existing stores list so that everything is exactly the same except the brands of variety not equal to 5 no longer appear.

**TO FURTHER CLARIFY:**

I have a list called 'Stores'. It contains 5 'Store' objects. Inside each of these objects are properties for each store. One of the properties is a list called 'Brands'. Inside this list there are 'Brand' objects that have a variety of different properties. I want to filter out all of the 'Brand' objects that don't have a particular value for one of the properties ('Variety' = 5). Once those are "filtered out" I want to return the original 'Stores' list exactly the way it was EXCEPT without the Brand objects inside the 'Brands' list that don't have the property value that I just specified ('Variety' = 5).

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: What is the question, exactly?!... You might add some piece of code for clearance...

Comment: Updated to further clarify and include what I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(var store in Stores)
{
  store.Brands=store.Brands.Where(b=>b.Variety==5).ToList();
}
```